# Calculated property on shared service across multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm sharing a service across multiple controllers. I've made this simplified fiddle to illustrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/ziaxdk/FFgpX/

```
app.service("common", function() {
var first = 1, second = 2;
return {
    first: first,
    second: second,
    // {{model.first+model.second}}    calculate this down here??
    calc: function() { return  first + second;  } // This line is not watched
}
```

});

How can I create calculated rules/properties on the service object so they get reflected to the view?

Regards,

Kenneth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really AngularJS-specific problem it is how closures work in JavaScript for primitive types. Basically when you've got a closure over a primitive type you are getting a copy of the original values instead of a reference to them. You are breaking the link. So in your code you've been changing different variable values then ones used to do calculation.

You could modify your service as follows:

```
app.service("common", function() {    
    return {
        first: 1,
        second: 2,        
        calc: function() { return  this.first + this.second;  }
    }
});
```

And your code becomes operational.

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nzY/2/